# Strange C# method call syntax

Tags: c#

Can you explain this method call syntax to me?

`this.mainParticleSystem.Simulate(time, withChildren: false, restart: true);`

Particularly I don't understand what `withChildren: false` parameters syntax means. Is it some kind of default value or something?

Comment: It's named parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: @KilianFoth thank you! Can you reformat your comment as answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are [Named Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

They were introduced together with optional arguments in C# 4.0 (VS 2010). Apparently the goal was not so much to support people who forget the order of method parameters, but to allow calling methods with many parameters while specifying only a few of them